# Recieving timeouts after adding try catch blocks

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, timeout, try-catch

I wrote some code that manipulates about 6 tables with lots of rows. I took about 4 min to get the job done, but it finished correctly. Later when I added more try catch blocks I started recieving timeouts. Is it possible that too many try catch blocks cause timeouts? If not what could have possibly gone wrong?

I first read the data from *.mdb via OleDbDataAdapter and then I read/write/update to MS SQL.

Comment: `I wrote some code` put that code here

Comment: Which dbms? (This is product specific behavior...)

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande it's a lot, more than 1000 lines.

Comment: try/catch blocks won't inherently cause issues. You have inadvertently changed the logic flow of your code. No one will be able to help you without seeing the code though.

Comment: Read this please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @bit It's literally too much code to paste and with the tfs version compare I clearly see only try catch blocks were added.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how often exceptions are thrown. Actually, try-catch bloc slows your code dramatically in case when exceptions are thrown. On my intel i5-4440 each catch block while debugging takes up to 30 milliseconds. So, some loop with 1000 iterations,  throwing and catching exceptions, will take 30 seconds to complete.

Simple proof code sample

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var timer = new Stopwatch();

    timer.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
    timer.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedTicks);

    timer.Reset();
    timer.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
    timer.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedTicks);
}
```

Output on my CPU (not in debug):

```
19119
13
```

Comment: I suspected something alonge those lines is the culprit. I'll try on a different computer and database.